# Facebook Connect not setting cookies

Tags: cookies, facebook

I'm trying to implement Facebook Connect on a website with .NET MVC using C#.

I've followed the instructions here: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Trying_Out_Facebook_Connect step by step. I can make the login work as in that when I log in through the site I'm also logged into Facebook.

In order to work with this in the server I think I need to access the cookies Facebook is supposed to leave like:

`APIKEY_user`
`APIKEY_session_key`
...

as mentioned here http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Verifying_The_Signature. 
The thing is I'm not getting any of these cookies. I've googled and it seems like I'm the only person with this problem. Any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong ? Has this happened to anyone else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that I was developing locally using localhost.

I resolved the problem by changing the settings for the application to point to a certain web address instead of localhost and changing my hosts file lo point that same web address to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

from the UI/client-side perspective, always insure you have the correct path indicated for the xd_receiver file in your FB.init() method.

Answer (score 0):

[Firecookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6683) is very useful for seeing what Cookies are/aren't being set.