# Passing Access Token from Facebook JS sdk to PHP session or cookie

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cookies

I am working by this Facebook example: [Getting Access Token From The JavaScript SDK Example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_access_token_from_javascript)

I am able to get the Facebook login part with JS just right.
But I want to get the user ID and Access Token from PHP for the server side actions such as Adding, Removing etc.

This is my JS part which works fine:

```
  function fb_login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            $.post("actions.php?js-login").done(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });         
            init_app();
        } else {
        alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    });
  }
```

And this is the PHP side which can't seem to recognize the cookie or session that the JS is supposed to transfer:

```
if (isset($_GET['js-login'])) {

$helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  echo 'No cookie set or no OAuth data could be obtained from cookie.';
  exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
exit;

}
```

I get the

> No cookie set or no OAuth data could be obtained from cookie.

Message, but the user is logged in by JS.

Comment: Did you find out ?  Got the same problem here... JS part works fine (FB login works) but it seems that then, no cookie is set.

Comment: Had to implant the cookie with JS... It works but it's not pretty.

Comment: According to [this page](https://www.sammyk.me/best-practice-for-facebook-login-with-the-javascript-sdk-and-php-sdk-v4-1), the cookie created shoule be name **fbsr_{_your-app-id_}**.  I just checked and no cookie is created for me.

Comment: + you should add your FB.init stuff in your question so we could be sure the problem does not comes from that.

Comment: I got this problem while developing on localhost, are u too ?  This could help : [use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1696932/782013) and [enable output_buffering in PHP.ini](http://www.tonegeek.com/ittechstuff/cookies-localhost-mam.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to initialize the JavaScript SDK with the

```
{cookie: true}
```

option set. For example:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: 'your-app-id',
    cookie: true, // This is important, it's not enabled by default
    version: 'v2.2'
  });
};
```

If you do not set this option, the Facebook cookie will not be set and the PHP SDK will not be able to obtain an access token from the signed request that exists in the cookie.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_access_token_from_javascript

Comment: is the cookie destroyed when FB.logout called???